# Designing a simple energy-efficient communication protocol?

Tags: wireless, communication, protocol, c++, digital-communications

What is the required background knowledge in order to be able to understand and work on the design of a communication protocol which has to be robust, simple and capable of coping with short contact times between nodes?

The signal has to be simply BPSK-modulated and the communication should take place in TDMA fashion.

Additionally, it has to be implemented in C++. Is it hard to implement such protocols in C++.

Can you show me some pointers as introduction that may be useful for the above-mentioned task.

Comment: Is your protocol supposed to be energy efficient as well as *about* energy efficiency? The title is confusing.

Comment: no, the protocol is supposed to be energy-efficient, the difficulties which it has to cope with raise from the requirement that is has to be energy-efficient. Anyways, I changed the title, maybe it is better now!

Comment: What precisely is the question - is it to do with background knowledge or the difficulty of implementing it in C++? What precisely do you mean by energy efficiency? What is an energy efficient protocol? Are you also considering hardware things that are not connected with protocol?

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet

Comment: IIRC the most efficient protocols do something where they disable the reciever as well asvthe transmitter when not in use and send a beacon when they turn back on for a few milliseconds.

Comment: @dextorb correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I know energy efficient ethernet is an 802.3 standard which does not fit to my case of wireless communication. Additionally, it is meant for the energy efficiency of the network equipments which deploy the standard, rather than being an energy-efficient protocol.

Comment: @Andyaka imagine you have microsensors (nodes) smaller than 1 cm with very small batteries, in that case you need a communication protocol which will use as little as possible energy. These nodes have to communicate which each other  in short fragments of time. Is it somehow clearer now?

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne I didn't see the wireless tag, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a "master" that is not reliant on battery power. It transmits RF markers at fixed intervals so that if a sensor needs to transmit it can recognize its time-slot. If the sensor wakes up and listens, it can calculate when to wake up again to transmit at the correct time-slot. This should minimize slave energy usage.

The master needs to transmit the active address for the current active time-slot and also the maximum address so that randomly listening slaves know how long to go to sleep for before their time-slot arrives.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: could you please provide me some pointers to materials where I can understand the concepts that you have mentioned to a greater extent? "can I take it from there?", unfortunately not, I need some (pre-)reading to reach to your point, and then some (post-)reading to continue where you have left. Thanks for the response tho'

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne everything that I wrote came clean out of my head so no references spring to mind because if I ever did read one it would have been over 30 years ago. Try looking up master and slave communications. The sensor I refer to is a slave and can only "communicate" when the master permits it. Permission is when the master gives it at the appropriate time slot. The maximum number of slaves on the system is known by the master and this info is given to any listening slave so that it can judge when to wake up. What specifically don't you understand? This can apply to radio or RS485.

Comment: Thanks for the extended clarification. Basically, I understand everything that you wrote (in both posts), however I would feel more secure if there was something specific to read, be it a textbook, or a survey. In my opinion there is a difference between understanding something, and grasping it. In order to achieve the task which I have explained in the original post, I guess I have to be in the second category. That's why I asked for some pointers. In any case, thanks again :)